# nvidia-smi always show non-zero GPU util and fan speed on a ubuntu 18.04 headless server

Tags: drivers, nvidia, fan, gpu

We have set up a new headless server with ubuntu 18.04 no-GUI version.
We installed the latest nvidia driver via `apt install nvidia-headless-510-server`. After that we also installed `nvidia-utils-510` so that we could monitor GPU usage via `nvidia-smi`.

But on this new server, the GPU fan speed is higher than usual, and the GPU utility is not zero despite no job is running.

```bsh
+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| NVIDIA-SMI 510.47.03    Driver Version: 510.47.03    CUDA Version: 11.6     |
|-------------------------------+----------------------+----------------------+
| GPU  Name        Persistence-M| Bus-Id        Disp.A | Volatile Uncorr. ECC |
| Fan  Temp  Perf  Pwr:Usage/Cap|         Memory-Usage | GPU-Util  Compute M. |
|                               |                      |               MIG M. |
|===============================+======================+======================|
|   0  NVIDIA GeForce ...  Off  | 00000000:01:00.0 Off |                  N/A |
| 41%   57C    P0   107W / 350W |      0MiB / 24576MiB |      3%      Default |
|                               |                      |                  N/A |
+-------------------------------+----------------------+----------------------+
|   1  NVIDIA TITAN Xp...  Off  | 00000000:21:00.0 Off |                  N/A |
| 25%   37C    P0    59W / 250W |      0MiB / 12288MiB |      0%      Default |
|                               |                      |                  N/A |
+-------------------------------+----------------------+----------------------+

+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| Processes:                                                                  |
|  GPU   GI   CI        PID   Type   Process name                  GPU Memory |
|        ID   ID                                                   Usage      |
|=============================================================================|
|  No running processes found                                                 |
+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------+
```

What did we do wrong? What is using the GPU constantly?

Comment: Hello. Since you have no monitor attached and a driver for no monitor what did you expect the GPU to be doing?

Comment: I would expect the GPUs doing nothing and have 0% usage. I totally have no idea what is using that 3% of GPU when no process is running.

Comment: That does not surprise me the card is installed it is getting power it is idling.